venia-ui- Magento PWA
I was asked to update venia/ui in my project.
I saw that there are lots of error in the move from version 7 to newest version so I decided to update for version 9.2.0 which is a version I have in another project.
I took the JSON of the second project and set the same version of all of the libraries.
when I run the project I got an error of imports GQL
one of the errors:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@magento/venia-ui/lib/components/CartPage/PriceAdjustments/ShippingMethods/shippingMethodsFragments.gql

when I checked in venia-ui library I saw that no of the GQL files I had in the past doesn't exist anymore.
I'm looking in web what is the solution of the changes but I can't find help data.
anyone know how to use all GQL files from magento 7 in magento 9 of above?
if there any replacement or o have to make this function custom?
I tried to update to closer version of venia ui. I can't find anything about the update of their GQL on web
